# Split large MySQL table into multiple files?

Tags: mysql, database

I am managing a MySQL server with several large tables (> 500 GB x 4 tables).  Each of these tables have similar properties:

- All tables have a timestamp column which is part of the primary key
- They are never deleted from
- They are updated only for a short period of time after being inserted
- Most of the reads occur for rows inserted within the past year
- Rarely but occasionally reads are done for longer back

We have several years worth of history (rows) and the rate at which we are accumulating rows is accelerating.  Right now these tables are all stored on disk with one-file-per-disk.  We are starting to run out of disk on the host machine and while we can buy more disk space I'd prefer to have a scalable strategy for dealing with ever increasing data.

Since the older records are never written to and rarely updated, I was hoping there would be a way to spread each of these large tables across multiple files using the timestamp column as a way of segregating the records.  Any files corresponding to records more than a year old, I'd like to keep in a networked file share.  This way they'll remain available to the server and we can limit the amount of disk needed locally for the data sub-1 year old.

I have some further hopes for good things (tm) from such splitting of tables across multiple files, but let's leave it there.

The questions then are

1. Is this a good idea?
2. How do I do this within MySQL?  I'm open to alternative storage technologies.

*Edit: If this approach isn't a good idea, what are some alternatives that meet the dual goals of avoiding single-host storage limitation and keeping the full data set accessible to DB clients?*

Comment: 1. No. 2. See partitioning

Comment: 1) Why not?

2) As I understand it partitioning alone doesn't achieve the horizontal separation I'm looking for, nor have I been successful at finding commands to communicate to MySQL that I'd like to use an increasing set of data files.

3) What would you suggest instead?